# Should we create multi stores with multi store views Or one store with multi store views?

Tags: magento2, b2b

**
We are going to create B2B Ecommerce Magento 2

Our Requirements

- different Customers With different Locations For Export
- different languages , currencies , products and prices

**

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use Single store with multi store views For different languages , currencies.
2. different Customers With different Locations For Export (Did not get it).

But if someone register on your website with single store then, magento already know that customer register from which store view. You can see that from customer section from admin panel.

Comment: We Need suggestion to create root category for Home Appliances B2B Ecommerce Magento2 
For different countries each country has different products, prices and languages
What is the best scenario to create it?